# Creating Contextmenu dynamically (not in Xaml)

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, telerik, radgridview

I have an application with many Views, and in many of them GridViews (actually RadGridViews from Telerik). I'm going to implement context menu functionality for every grid so that the user can either copy row(s) or copy a specific cell. For the moment I'm doing like the following:

```
                <telerik:RadContextMenu.ContextMenu>
                    <telerik:RadContextMenu x:Name="radContextMenu">
                        <telerik:RadMenuItem Header="Copy...">
                            <telerik:RadMenuItem.Icon>
                                <TextBlock Text="&#xE653;" HorizontalAlignment="Center" />
                            </telerik:RadMenuItem.Icon>
                            <telerik:RadMenuItem Header="Selected Row(s)" Command="{Binding Commands.CopySelectedRowsCommand, Mode=TwoWay}">
                                <interactivity:Interaction.Behaviors>
                                    <localbehaviors:SetSelectedRowsToCommandParameterBehavior />
                                </interactivity:Interaction.Behaviors>
                            </telerik:RadMenuItem>
                            <telerik:RadMenuItem Header="Cell Text" 
                                                 Command="{Binding Commands.CopyCellTextCommand, Mode=TwoWay}">
                                <interactivity:Interaction.Behaviors>
                                    <localbehaviors:SetCellValueToCommandParameterBehavior/>
                                </interactivity:Interaction.Behaviors>
                            </telerik:RadMenuItem>
                        </telerik:RadMenuItem>
                        <telerik:RadMenuItem Header="Email" Command="{Binding Commands.EmailCommand, Mode=TwoWay}">
                            <telerik:RadMenuItem.Icon>
                                <TextBlock Text="&#xE603;" HorizontalAlignment="Center" />
                            </telerik:RadMenuItem.Icon>
                            <interactivity:Interaction.Behaviors>
                                <localbehaviors:SetSelectedRowsWithHeadersToCommandParameterBehavior />
                            </interactivity:Interaction.Behaviors>
                        </telerik:RadMenuItem>
                    </telerik:RadContextMenu>
                </telerik:RadContextMenu.ContextMenu>
```

But because there are so many grids in this application (around 75 different grids) I want to move this part to a class, let's say RadGridViewCopyFunctionality, that for instance will inherit from ControlPanelItem in Telerik.Windows.Controls.GridView.ControlPanelItems, and there implement the functionality I need for my context menu. The Xaml-code will then just be:

```
                <telerik:RadGridView.ControlPanelItems>
                    <frameworkControls:RadGridViewCopyFunctionality Icon="{x:Static commonIcons:NavigationIcon.Menu}" />
                </telerik:RadGridView.ControlPanelItems>
```

By doing this the code will be less repetitive, and easier to maintain. The problem is I just can't get this to work. If anyone could just Point me in the right direction, or even show me if there are other ways to go to implement this functionality in code. Any help is appreciated.

Thanks,
Peter

Comment: What about `Style`? It would be applied to every GridView in your application.

Comment: Yes, but I didn't know it's possible to use behaviors when you for instance use a ResourceDictionary.

Comment: Yes, especially when you use `ContextMenu` as it is not part of your visual tree, it will inherit DataContext of wherever it has been declared.